# .NET Core DI passing info of AddHttpContextAccessor to a service

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, controller

In my solution I have projects for my API, my Web App and also have another project which includes services, that are getting some information from a database and formatting them, these are currently only used by this API, but these could be used by other API projects in the future.

My API have a couple controllers that are returning JSON data from the result returned by the services.

In some cases the services needs to call the API to process some information before calling the request to the database.  Since I have dev/staging/prod environment with their own URL I don't want to hardcode the URLs in the services I want to use DI to get these dynamicaly depending on the context.

In the Startup.cs of my API I have added services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); in the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) section to gain access to the current http context :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
   ...
}
```

With that I know I can now access the information directly into my controller which I tried and it worked :

```
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
    private readonly string _baseUrl;


    public FeaturesController(...
                                ,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        ...
        _baseUrl = UrlHelpers.ShowBaseURL(httpContextAccessor) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_baseUrl));
    }
}

public static class UrlHelpers
{
    public static string ShowBaseURL(IHttpContextAccessor httpcontextaccessor)
    {
        var request = httpcontextaccessor.HttpContext.Request;

        var absoluteUri = string.Concat(
            request.Scheme,
            "://",
            request.Host.ToUriComponent(),
            request.PathBase.ToUriComponent());
        return absoluteUri;
    }
}
```

I could do just about the same thing in the services but to me they should not act directly on the httpcontext, since this is not the job they are meant to do. I am sure I could do better by adding a class injected of some sort that would have then make the specific value available to my services.

I know I could also pass the _baseUrl directly as an argument when calling the services from my controller but since I am trying to better understand DI and use it I would rather find another way if it is viable.

Comment: I'm possibly misunderstanding, but it seems as if your services are calling into the API as that the same Controllers expose that call into those services? That seems like an indirect cyclic dependency (controller calling service, service calling controller through API). As those Controllers forward the call to the serices anyway, why don't you let the services call into other services directly? Wouldn't that remove the problem you are having and remove a lot of overhead?

Comment: It's a good idea I will look into this and see if I can make it works in my architecture in the meantime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give credit but I went with Steven solution which make the most sens